# Inserir imagem com função kableExtra::spec_image( )

Tags: r, imagem

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
```

Suponha o seguinte dataset:

```
games <- tibble(logo = "",
                nome = c("Joao", "Pedro", "Geovanna"),
                medalha = c("Gold", "Silver","Bronze"))
```

Quero acrescentar imagens (.png) das medalhas correspondentes.
Criei um PROJETO (File > New Project...) para trabalhar com esses dados, de modo a não me preocupar com definição do caminho completo para os arquivos.

Assim, tenho uma pasta chamada "img" onde estão os seguintes arquivos:

- 1024px-Bronze_medal.png
- 1024px-Gold_medal.png
- 1024px-Silver_medal.png

Para inserir as imagens das medalhas, fiz o seguinte:

```
games %>% 
  kable() %>% 
  kable_paper(full_width = T) %>% 
  column_spec(1, image = spec_image(c("img/1024px-Gold_medal.png",
                                      "img/1024px-Silver_medal.png",
                                      "img/1024px-Bronze_medal.png"), 200,200))
```

Quando fiz o *knit* o resultado foi conforme o esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O inconveniente foi que precisei informar cada um dos caminhos na função `spec_image()`.

Estou tentando **otimizar** esse processo. Para tanto, imaginei o seguinte: utilizar a função `sprintf()` para criar uma nova coluna no dataset (que chamei de "link". Me preocupei em inserir as aspas) com os caminhos e passar essa coluna recem-criada como argumento para a função `spec_image()`

```
games %>% 
  mutate(link = sprintf("'img/1024px-%s_medal.png'", medalha)) %>% 
  kable() %>% 
  kable_paper(full_width = T) %>% 
  column_spec(1, image = spec_image("link", 200,200))
```

No entanto, na hora de fazer o knit surge a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
File link not found in resource path
Erro: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99
```

Pensei que ao referenciar a coluna "link" na função `spec_image()` seria a mesma coisa `spec_image(c("img/1024px-Gold_medal.png", "img/1024px-Silver_medal.png", "img/1024px-Bronze_medal.png"))`

Comment: Se você referenciar a posição absoluta, não resolve? /home/user/img/1024px-Silver_medal.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu resolvi o problema, mas talvez não seja a resposta procurada.

(releve as imagens das medalhas. como elas não foram fornecidas no post original, eu procurei outras na internet)

O truque que usei foi criar o objeto `link` fora do *pipe*, de modo a não confundir o `dplyr` e o `kable`.

```r
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)

games <- tibble(logo = "",
                nome = c("Joao", "Pedro", "Geovanna"),
                medalha = c("Gold", "Silver","Bronze"))

medalha <- c("Gold", "Silver", "Bronze")

link <- sprintf("img/1024px-%s_medal.png", medalha)

kable(games) %>% 
  kable_paper(full_width = T) %>% 
  column_spec(1, image = spec_image(link, 200, 200))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entendo que, embora esteja funcionando, esta talvez não seja a solução procurada pelo AP. Entretanto, em um post no fórum do RStudio intitulado [Conditional formatting with column_spec within a dplyr chain](https://community.rstudio.com/t/conditional-formatting-with-column-spec-within-a-dplyr-chain/84347/4), Hao Zhu, o autor do pacote `kableExtra`, resolve o problema que é posto lá de maneira similar. Ele inclusive comenta o seguinte:

> The solution is quite simple: save the final data before you create your table. Well, I understand the joy of piping from top to bottom. However, in cases like this one, it's just easier and cleaner to break them into two pieces.

Em uma tradução livre,

> A solução é bastante simples: salve o conjunto de dados final antes de criar a sua tabela. Bem, eu entendo a satisfação de criar um *pipe* do começo ao fim do seu código. Entretanto, em casos como este, é apenas mais fácil e limpo quebrá-los em duas partes.

Comment: Muito legal Marcus. Obrigado. Só uma dúvida: é a primeira vez que ofereço recompensa. Como faz para "pagar" a recompensa? É automático ou preciso apenas aceitar sua resposta como a correta?

Comment: 24 horas após o início da oferta da recompensa, basta clicar no ícone de concessão de gratificação ao lado da resposta a ser recompensada. [Mais detalhes podem ser encontrados neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) (embora não hajam imagens descrevendo o procedimento).